# Getting a corruption error when running a `git push`

Tags: git, version-control, corruption

I tried to run `git push` and got a corruption error:

```
% git push
Counting objects: 62, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
error: corrupt loose object 'f2310668fe335b36c513e50fcd99744e8fd5c2e0'
fatal: object f2310668fe335b36c513e50fcd99744e8fd5c2e0 is corrupted
error: pack-objects died with strange error
```

This hangs on the last line until I hit `Ctrl+C`.

I read that running `git gc` might help, so I did that and got a similar error:

```
% git gc
Counting objects: 493, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
error: corrupt loose object 'f2310668fe335b36c513e50fcd99744e8fd5c2e0'
fatal: object f2310668fe335b36c513e50fcd99744e8fd5c2e0 is corrupted
error: failed to run repack
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone a backup of your repository. If the corrupted object id is $OBJECTID, do this:

In new repository:

```
git cat-file -t $OBJECTID > object-type
git cat-file $(cat object-type) $OBJECTID > object-contents
```

Move those two new files to the old repository

In corrupt repository, move away your corrupt object:

```
mv .git/objects/XX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX .
git hash-object -t $(cat object-type) -w object-contents
```

This should write the object into git's database, and output $OBJECTID to STDOUT. If it outputs some other SHA1 id, you have made a mistake and you should delete that wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it is one of your own recent objects that you are trying to push that contains a corrupt object. Do

```
git fetch
```

then rebase your changes on top of the remote tracking branch. If you're in a fast forward situation, this should do nothing

```
git rebase origin/yourbranch
```

if it's not a ff situation, you should be getting an error on the commit that is either itself corrupt or something it points to in the tree and blob structure it points to.

If this was a ff situation, do a

```
git rebase -i origin/yourbranch
```

don't change anything. Save and quit and git will rewrite the commits on top of where they are. This should fail no a commit that will help you track down the bad object.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try to re-clone your repo from an external source, and then fetch the changes form your own changed one. This works if the defect object is not created by one of your own commits.

```
git clone http://foo/bar
cd bar
git fetch ../orig [branch1:branch1 [branch2:branch2[...]]]
```

You can also try to extract object f2310668fe335b36c513e50fcd99744e8fd5c2e0 from the fresh clone and place it into `.git/objects/f2/310668fe335b36c513e50fcd99744e8fd5c2e0` and run `git gc` again, but do this with a copy of your repo.